# How do I add an clicklistener to a row in table Layout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout, tablerow

i want to make a table layout in which there are 2 rows.

*In both rows there are one Label and a Text Field when i press the 1st row or 2nd row the prompt Dialog will open and u enter any value it will set on Text field of selected row.*

please guide me how to make a click listener on row with example and how to call a dialog when the row is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give each TableRow element a unique id and define an `onClick`

**method:**

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:onClick="rowClick">
```

Find the row by id from layout and then add following in java class

```
 tableRow= (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.one);

     tableRow.setClickable(true);
        tableRow.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

private OnClickListener onClickListener= new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            show_dialog();

        }
    };
```

Then Call Following Method

```
public void show_dialog() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        dialog.setTitle("yor title");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        final Button btnOkDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ResetOkBtn);
        btnOkDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {


            }
        });
        try {
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TableRow row1 = findViewById(R.id.row2);
row1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// do any thing

    }
});

// Method 2 ********************
TableRow row1 = findViewById(R.id.row2);
row1.setonClickListner(this);

public void onClicl(View v)
{
switch (v.getId())
         {
         case R.id.row1: 

             break;
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give your TableRow an id on your xml  file

```
<TableRow 
   android:id="@+id/row1"
   ...
>
```

Set the children of your row(in your case a TextView and an EditText probably) to NOT clickable

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Now on your java file find your tablerow with the id and add onClickListener

```
TableRow row1 = findViewById(R.id.row1);
d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Now to open a dialog read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Just a guess.
Make the EditText clickable. It might be what you are really looking for

Comment: you should set the row to clickable and it's children to non-clickable.
If it's still not working provide some code so we can see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
//if we want to applay listener on dynamic tablerow then use this
//sure that perfect 
 TablRowe tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setClickable(true);
tr.setId(100);// if in loop then add 1 counter with 100 like (100+counter) at end count++ it
 tr.setOnClickListener(this);
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
{


        switch (v.getId())
         {
         case 100: 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "100", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
             break;

         case 101:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "101", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             break;
}
```